# How to avoid a textfile getting changed when exported as HTML?

Tags: export, html

How can I export whatever I like to an HTML file, without Mathematica ensuring that it conforms to any standard? In other words, how can I get Mathematica simply to assign an .html suffix to a string I'm exporting?

Comment: Something like `Export["name.html", "exported string", "String"]`?

Comment: That works. Thanks! I've now also found `Export["name.txt", "exported string"]; RenameFile["name.txt", "name.html"]`.

Comment: Further investigation has shown that using Export followed by RenameFile is better, because unlike the Export as "String" method it retains the line feeds.

Comment: Presumably you would just use "Text" instead of "String" then.

Comment: Yes - that fixes it.

Comment: Just a general comment, `"String"` is a byte-based format, so generally in my experience `"Text"` has a few fewer surprises, as @CarlWoll pointed out. One case where `"Text"` can be worse than `"String"` is in performance, as it does some degree of conversion I believe.